# Can anyone think of a simple way to attribute a socket to the thread that created it?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I'm trying to attribute an already created socket to a particular thread on the windows platform.

I'm trying to do this without debug APIs and stack traces.  It may come down to diverting the ws2_32 library calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "attribute a socket" ?

Comment: Attribute: determine which thread a)created or b)is reading from/writing to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; Windows does not keep track of this information. Sockets (and all kernel objects) are created by *processes* without regard for which thread created them. GDI objects have thread affinity, but kernel objects don't.

Comment: I figured the data wasn't saved anywhere when I couldn't find an API for it at all.  Thanks for confirming.  I'll give it the check after a day or so.  I don't think most people read most answered questions and vote